# Gibt es ein deutsches magisches Quadrat?

Tags: curiosity

Gibt es ein deutsches magisches Quadrat, das dieselben Symmetrieeigenschaften hat, wie das lateinische magische Quadrat?

```
SATOR
AREPO
TENET
OPERA
ROTAS
```

Arepo ist möglicherweise ein Name, eine mögliche Übersetzung wäre dann
Der Sämann Arepo hält mit Mühe die Räder.

Comment: Es ist nicht so deutlich, welche Symmetrieeigenschaften du meinst. Muss die Ecke wie "123/245/356" sein, und durch die X- und Y-Axes (die TENETs) reflektiert sein?

Comment: Für die Nichtlateiner wäre es hilfreich, wenn dargestellt würde, wo sich überall Worte verbergen, und was sie bedeuten - bspw.: Sind das alles Substantive? Außer Opera, das kennt man auch so, das ist der frührömische Webbrowser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of completely symmetric **4x4 squares**, e.g those in splattne's answers and:

```
KREM   TRAB  ESSE
REHE   ROMA  SEES
EHER   AMOR  SEES
MERK   BART  ESSE
```

Some **5x5 squares**, admittedly bending the rules a little, are:

```
ETTER
TRAGE
TAHAT - höchste Berg Algeriens
EGART
RETTE
```

```
STARB 
THIER - Tier, Variante bis 1901
AITIA - Ursache
REIHT
BRATS
```

Without using proper names, there were none possible from my wordlist. A weak case could be made for a **6x6 square**, too:

```
STAATS
TALLAT - Art von Kaffee
ALUULA - Stadt in Somalia
ALUULA
TALLAT
STAATS
```

Answer (score 12):

*tl;dr:* Es gibt keine symmetrischen magischen Buchstabenquadrate mit einer 5x5 (oder größeren) Matrix. Es gibt jedoch viele 4x4-Quadrate.

---

Um die Frage zu beantworten, habe ich ein kleines Computerprogramm geschrieben, das – basierend auf einer [Liste deutscher Wörter](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words) – magische Quadrate erstellt.

Zuerst habe ich alle deutschen Wörter mit fünf Buchstaben berücksichtigt. Mein Programm hat hunderttausende (!) verschiedene magische Quadrate gefunden. Einige Wortkombinationen sind sehr amüsant:

```
ALLES    VOLLE    BEZUG    FRANZ    STARK
LEERT    OBOEN    ELENA    ROMEO    TÜREN
LERNE    LOTET    ZERRT    AMOUR    ARNIE
ERNST    LEERE    UNRAT    NEUER    REIBT
STETS    ENTEN    GATTE    ZORRO    KNETE
```

Allerdings geht es in der Fragestellung um **Quadrate mit Wörtern, die auch rückwärts gelesen** einen Sinn ergeben – (streng ausgelegt sollten die Wörter zudem symmetrisch sein). Deshalb habe ich zuerst derartig beschaffene Wörter gesucht. Davon gibt es 56 in der Wortliste, die ich verwendet habe (einige von ihnen sind übrigens [Palindrome](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrom)):

```
ABEBA/ABEBA, AMINA/ANIMA, ANIMA/AMINA, ARTET/TETRA, ASSAM/MASSA, 
ASSET/TESSA, CIVIC/CIVIC, DEKAN/NAKED, EDLEM/MELDE, EIGER/REGIE, 
ENGES/SEGNE, ETATS/STATE, ETHAN/NAHTE, GILES/SELIG, KAJAK/KAJAK, 
LAGER/REGAL, LEBEN/NEBEL, LEBER/REBEL, LEGER/REGEL, LEIHT/THIEL, 
LEVEL/LEVEL, MASSA/ASSAM, MELDE/EDLEM, MENEM/MENEM, MILES/SELIM, 
NAHTE/ETHAN, NAKED/DEKAN, NEBEL/LEBEN, NEBEN/NEBEN, NEGER/REGEN, 
NEHER/REHEN, NEUEN/NEUEN, NEVEN/NEVEN, RADAR/RADAR, REBEL/LEBER, 
REGAL/LAGER, REGEL/LEGER, REGEN/NEGER, REGER/REGER, REGES/SEGER, 
REGIE/EIGER, REHEN/NEHER, ROTOR/ROTOR, SEGER/REGES, SEGNE/ENGES, 
SELES/SELES, SELIG/GILES, SELIM/MILES, SILOS/SOLIS, SOLIS/SILOS, 
SOLOS/SOLOS, STATE/ETATS, STETS/STETS, TESSA/ASSET, TETRA/ARTET, 
THIEL/LEIHT
```

Dann habe ich mein Programm noch einmal laufen lassen und als "Wortschatz" nur die 56 Wörter verwendet. Leider fand das Programm **kein gültiges 5x5-Quadrat**. Es gibt auch kein einziges 5x5-Quadrat, in dem *vier* Wörter korrekt passen würden; bei drei passenden Wörtern ist Schluss.

---

Ich habe dasselbe dann für ein **4x4-Quadrat** versucht. Hier sieht es besser aus. Es gibt tatsächlich 315 magische 4x4-Quadrate, bei denen auch die rückwärts gelesene Buchstabenkombinationen gültige Wörter sind, zum Beispiel

```
IMAM    WERD    SARG    HERD
META    EHER    AMOR    EUER
ATEM    REHE    ROMA    REUE
MAMI    DREH    GRAS    DREH
```

Die 315 Quadrate enthalten allerdings auch Wortkombinationen, bei denen einzelne Wörter doppelt vorkommen, zum Beispiel

```
SISI
ISIS
SISI
ISIS
```

---

Als Draufgabe noch ein nettes 6x6 (nicht-symmetrisches) Buchstabenquadrat, das mein Programm ausgespuckt hat:

```
KLASSE
LADIES
ADONIS
SINGLE
SEILEN
ESSENZ
```

und alle 7x7-Quadrate – ebenfalls nicht symmetrisch:

```
BEATLES      FIEBERT (oder SIEBERT)
EINHEIT      INNERER
ANREISE      ENDLOSE
THEATER      BELEBEN
LEITERN      EROBERN    
EISERNE      RESERVE
STERNEN      TRENNEN
```

Comment: Ich verkaufe ein "bohre" (Ich bohrte in /usr/share/dict/ngerman mit spärlichem Erfolg: 8 Funde).

Comment: Nice! (None of these is as symmetric as thei's example, though.)

Comment: @Tim the 4x4 squares are symmetric.

Comment: You're right, I missed them!

Answer (score 6):

Hallo, es gibt zwei 4x4 Quadrate, die etwas in der Richtung darstellen

```
REBE
EBER
BEIL
ERLE

RATE
EGON
BILD
ELLE
```

Im Englischen gibt es für 5x5 [laut Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square) z.B.

```
HEART
EMBER
ABUSE
RESIN
TREND
```

Für 5x5 habe ich drei gefunden, die allerdings nicht rückwärts sinn ergeben.

LAMPE, AREAL, MEUTE, PATENT, ELEND

REISE, EINER, INSEL, SEELE, ERLEN

MASKE, ABTEI, STAUB, KEULE, EIBEN

Deswegen ist meine Vemrutung, dass es im Deutschen kein SATOR-Quadrat existiert.
Ich hoffe, das hilft.

Comment: Thanks for editing :) I'm not very familiar with the codes, sorry

Comment: No problem :) Welcome to german.SE! You can find formatting help in the sidebar to the right of the "new answer" field.

Comment: Die 4x4-Quadrate sind aber nicht symmetrisch, v. a. BILD und ERLE ergeben rückwärts gelesen kein richtiges Wort.

Answer (score 2):

Ich hab' auch eins:

```
LOL
OHO
LOL
```

aber das war nicht sonderlich Deutsch im LOL-Teil, muss ich zugeben, ich lege also nach:

```
BUB
UHU
BUB
```

Comment: What does "oho" mean?

Comment: It's an interjection, nowadays usually used ironically. It is meant to express admiration for what someone has done or just said.