# Online dictionary where I can search for second half of compound noun

Tags: resource, compound

For example *die Wertsachen*, I want to find all words which end in *die Sache*.
Other example, nouns ending in *-gerät* or *-dienst*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of leo.org you can type e.g. `*gerät` or `*dienst` to search for certain patterns. [Search Tipps](http://dict.leo.org/pages/help/ende/searchTips_de.html) is your friend.

Comment: The same is true for `dict.cc`. Here is the [tips page](http://www.dict.cc/?s=about%3Atips).

Comment: and for [dix.osola](http://dix.osola.com/index.php).

Answer (score 6):

[Elexiko](http://www.owid.de/suche/elex/erweitert?pattern=p_end&wort=sache&ortho=ka&wortart=ka&wobi=ka&parad=ka&semk=ka)  can do that.

You can also look for a "Rückläufiges Wörterbuch". In such a dictionary, entries are in alphabetical order with regard to their last letters rather than the first ones. So worde that share an ending (rather than a beginning) are grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

In a compound noun (*Kompositum*), the first part is the *Bestimmungswort*, the second is the *Grundwort*. In your example, *Wert* is the *Bestimmungswort*. If you want to search using the *Grundwort* as the criterion, your best bet is [Wörterbuchnetz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/).

In addition to the venerable *Deutsches Wörterbuch* started by the Brothers Grimm in the 19th century and still being updated, a couple dozen dictionaries ranging from etymological to medieval German will be searched in parallel, with the results tagged according to source dictionary. All the dictionaries are professionally edited, no crowdsourced works among them.

Put an asterisk directly in front of the *Grundwort* like so:

> *sache

and you get hundreds of hits, from *Abhandlungssache* to *Zweckursache*. (The latter, however, is a false positive -- *Ursache* is a different *Grundwort* from *Sache* -- so be careful.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can write little programms or scripts, you may take some word lists from [Where can I find a parsable list of German words?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words?rq=1) and write a little parser.

Perhaps different encodings make it a bit difficult.

An example: My answer to [Einsamkeit und Zweisamkeit](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7339/974) was generated with this ruby script:

```
#encoding: utf-8
treffer = []
{
  'top10000de.txt' => 'r:cp1252:utf-8',  #http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/html/wliste.html
  'german.0' => 'r:cp1252:utf-8',        #Quelle: http://www.htdig.org/files/contrib/wordlists/GermanWordlist.zip
  'de-en.txt' => 'r:utf-8',              #Quelle: ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/Local/urz/ding/de-en/de-en.txt
  'german.dic' => 'r:cp1252:utf-8',      #http://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/files/
  'derewo-v-ww-bll-320000g-2012-12-31-1.0.txt' => 'r:cp1252:utf-8', #http://www.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html
}.each{|filename,mode|
  puts "====#{filename}"
  File.open(File.join('wordlists', filename), mode){|f|
    #~ f.each_line{|word|
    f.read.split(/\s+/).each{|word|
      #Conversion 'german.0'
      word.gsub!(/(\/.*\Z)/, '')
      word.gsub!(/A"/, 'Ä')
      word.gsub!(/a"/, 'ä')
      word.gsub!(/o"/, 'ö')
      word.gsub!(/o"/, 'Ö')
      word.gsub!(/u"/, 'ü')
      word.gsub!(/U"/, 'Ü')
      word.gsub!(/sS/, 'ß')

      #Get all words ending with "samkeit"          
      treffer << word if word =~ /samkeit$/
    }
  }
}

treffer.uniq! #delete duplicates
puts treffer.size
puts treffer.sort.map{|w| "- #{w}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unixoid system with Aspell you can probably use the following one-liner:

```
aspell -l de dump master | aspell -l de expand | sed "s/ /\\n/g" | grep "dienst$"
```

Where *dienst* is the suffix.

Brief explanation:

- `aspell -l de dump master` yields the raw data of the German dictionary.
- `aspell -l de expand` expands each entry to all valid words formed formable from that entry (like inflected variants of a word).
- `sed "s/ /\\n/g"` converts the result to a newline-separated list.
- `grep` filters those lines (words), showing only those that have `dienst` before the end of the line (denoted by `$`).

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/) allows listing its entries in order of their last, next-to-last, etc. letters, thereby [providing a reverse dictionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategorie:R%C3%BCckl%C3%A4ufige_W%C3%B6rterliste_%28Deutsch%29) (example: [words ending in *gerät*](https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategorie:R%C3%BCckl%C3%A4ufige_W%C3%B6rterliste_%28Deutsch%29&pagefrom=t%C3%A4reg)).