# Einsamkeit und Zweisamkeit

Tags: noun, synonym, vocabulary

I have just encountered the word "Zweisamkeit". Till this moment I knew only "Einsamkeit" und "Gemeinsamkeit". Do you know any other words like this?

Comment: Are you after *Ein-* vs. *Zwei-*, or is it the suffix *-keit*, or *-samkeit* you are interested in?

Comment: It's rather -keit/-samkeit, but the meaning is also important. All these words are somehow connected.

Comment: @KseniaMurach motivated on your question, I asked [this](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/german-dicctionary-with-reverse-words), which if solved, may be helpful here.

Comment: @c.p. thank you, that's an interesting question.

Comment: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zweisamkeit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [made a quick search in some word lists](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7340/974) and found 133 words with ~samkeit.

There are many repetition because of compound words.

> Achtsamkeit
>    Alleinwirksamkeit
>    Alltagswirksamkeit
>    Anhaltsamkeit
>    Anschmiegsamkeit
>    Antigenwirksamkeit
>    Arbeitsamkeit
>    Artilleriewirksamkeit
>    Aufmerksamkeit
>    Außenwirksamkeit
>    Außenwirkung/Außenwirksamkeit
>    Bedachtsamkeit
>    Bedeutsamkeit
>    Behutsamkeit
>    Beredsamkeit
>    Bergeinsamkeit
>    Beschäftigungswirksamkeit
>    Betriebsamkeit
>    Biegsamkeit
>    Bildsamkeit
>    Bildwirksamkeit
>    Breitenwirksamkeit
>    Buchgelehrsamkeit
>    Büchergelehrsamkeit
>    Bühnenwirksamkeit
>    Datensparsamkeit
>    Daueraufmerksamkeit
>    Dreisamkeit
>    Duldsamkeit
>    Ehrsamkeit
>    Eigenbedeutsamkeit
>    Einfühlsamkeit
>    Einprägsamkeit
>    Einsamkeit
>    Empfindsamkeit
>    Energiegenügsamkeit
>    Enthaltsamkeit
>    Erfolgswirksamkeit
>    Erholsamkeit
>    Exportwirksamkeit
>    Fachgelehrsamkeit
>    Feldeinsamkeit
>    Feuerwirksamkeit
>    Finanzwirksamkeit
>    Folgsamkeit
>    Friedsamkeit
>    Furchtsamkeit
>    Fügsamkeit
>    Gehorsamkeit
>    Gelehrsamkeit
>    Gemeinsamkeit
>    Genügsamkeit
>    Geruhsamkeit
>    Geschichtswirksamkeit
>    Gesetzesgelehrsamkeit
>    Gewaltsamkeit
>    Gottesgelehrsamkeit
>    Grausamkeit
>    Grundaufmerksamkeit
>    Grundgemeinsamkeit
>    Hauptaufmerksamkeit
>    Heilsamkeit
>    Höhenruderwirksamkeit
>    Hörsamkeit
>    Kanzelberedsamkeit
>    Kleidsamkeit

Comment: Thank you. That's really impressive. How did you manage to get that list?

Comment: Many of these words are rather unusual to put it politely - what source did you use to generate this list?

Comment: Kanzelberedsamkeit :D

Comment: I linked the script for my search. I used wordlists from http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words?lq=1 (The script contains the source links - I don't know if they are still valid.

Answer (score 3):

### Double suffixation *"-sam"* and *"-keit"*

This admittedly peculiar construct results from a double suffixation. In the first place a noun was turned to an adjective by adding the suffix *-sam*, then it is turned back to a noun with another suffix *"-keit"*.

### [Suffix *"-sam"*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=-sam)

This is a rather old suffix which is already present in Old High German, but also in Old English. It was and still is used to convert a noun to an adjective with the meaning of something *being of the kind or nature* of the noun it was added to. Later this suffix was also used to convert verbs to adjectives.

- gemeinsam
- langsam
- wirksam

### [Suffix *"-keit/-heit"*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=-keit)

The likewise old suffixes *"-keit"*, and *"-heit"* are both used in the same meaning. Originally it was used for a *shape, person, nature, standing* but when added to an adjective this was thereby nominalized with the noun being *something of the shape or nature of* the adjective it was added to.

- Gesundheit
- Ewigkeit
- Wahrheit

When suffixing adjectives from above that were build by suffixing a noun with *-sam* we end with the resulting double suffixed noun from your examples (which then will have a different meaning from the rooting noun):

- Gemeinsamkeit
- Langsamkeit
- Wirksamkeit

It is not unusual to have constructs being build from several suffixes leading to such hard to decompose words like

- Wahrhaftigkeit

Comment: In this case numerals "ein" and "zwei" were converted to adjectives and after that to nouns. It's pretty much like construction set.

Answer (score 1):

Unter dem Begriff „Zweisamkeit“ versteht man meist ein harmonisches, oft romantisches Zusammensein von zwei Personen, ohne störende andere Personen oder negative Einflüsse.

That means, “Zweisamkeit” is used to describe a harmonic, romantic partnership/situation of 2 people without negative influence of other people or any negative aspect.

Example:

> Sandra und Oliver lebten bis zu ihrem Lebensende in harmonischer
>   Zweisamkeit.
>
> Sandra und Oliver verbrachten ihren Urlaub auf einer einsamen Insel in
>   gemütlicher Zweisamkeit.

Comment: The question was not about meaning. But anyway I appreciate your help. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Maybe this was not what @KseniaMurach was after, but I like your answer much more, because it focuses on the fact that "Zweisamkeit" is not a regular word like all the others in the list, but a pun playing on "Einsamkeit". (Even though you are citing without giving the source (http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zweisamkeit)).

Comment: I see, in fact I have read the question more in view of the meaning between the words Einsamkeit, Zweisamkeit and Gemeinsamkeit.

Comment: Is the first paragraph rather a quote, then please put it in quote blocks and add a link. Or is it your own statement, then please translate to English. An answer should be monolingual (except for examples and quotes) and, preferably, in the same language as the question was asked.

Comment: @Em1 It wasn't a quote, it's my own statement but putted into the quote tag because people would write it like this. The question was not about the translation of Zweisamkeit (togetherness), but next time I will put a translation of my examples as well then.

Comment: Oh, forget about that. It's fine that the example are in German and you don't need to add a translation. The point is, I didn't read your answer, just realized your second paragraph starts with "That means". I was thinking that you explain your first paragraph "Unter dem Begriff...", but now I see that this is a translation rather than a explanation. That is, everything's OK. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Em1: Oh, and I thought you are talking about the examples which aren't in fact not translated. Like you said, everything's OK. :)

Comment: @netsetter Well, as stated above the most part of your first paragraph is a quote, or did you write the wiktionary article (see under "Bedeutung")? Even if you quote yourself, please mark it as a quote and give the source, because your sources might be helpful to other members of the board, especially the one asking the question: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zweisamkeit