# German dictionary with reverse words

Tags: dictionary

Is there a German online dictionary that renders all (standard) German words by inputting the last letters?

Say, you input “*nebierhcs*”, then you get, for instance, *schreiben, abschreiben, anschreiben, …* (and perhaps some words I'm missing inbetween). That is, one can pick the number of letters in common, the output words are supposed to have as last letters.

---

This question was somehow motivated by [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7333/einsamkeit-und-zweisamkeit).

Comment: A few months ago a reverse online dictionary for German existed, but trying to answer your question, I noticed that it’s gone. [This](http://www.denic.de/domains/transit/transit-informationsseite.html) was its adress, just in case that this is any help.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Your link it to the information page you were redirected to when trying to open the address. :-)

Comment: @Chirlu: Indeed, [here](http://www.rückläufigeswörterbuch.de/) is the hopefully correct (dead) link.

Comment: See also http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/491/where-can-i-find-a-parsable-list-of-german-words?rq=1 I used some of the lists to generate [my answer to the _Einsamkeit und Zweisamkeit_-question](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/7339/974)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/online-dictionary-where-i-can-search-for-second-half-of-compound-noun?lq=1)

[Link to the dictionary](http://www.owid.de/suche/elex/erweitert)

Comment: Super! auch die `*-Ende_des_Wortes`-Suche in dict.cc funktionierte.