# How to perform an advanced search of German nouns in Wiktionary restricting both gender and ending?

Tags: dictionary

*I hope you could give this question a try before closing it. It's, admittedly, not*  directly *related to German, but if a successful answer is provided, I'm sure it will be useful – at least for German learners – in finding counterexamples. Moreover, if I pose it in other site, I'm sure it will be closed faster.*

There are some answers providing search techniques that are incredibly easy and very useful:

- [Online dictionary where I can search for second half of compound noun](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/online-dictionary-where-i-can-search-for-second-half-of-compound-noun/7340#7340)
- [Einsamkeit und Zweisamkeit](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7333/einsamkeit-und-zweisamkeit/7339#7339)

The thing is that I've tried to search in [Elexiko](http://www.owid.de/suche/elex/erweitert?pattern=p_end&wort=ung&ortho=ka&lsanz=ka&wortart=nom&gram=nom_2&wobi=ka&semk=ka&parad=ka&gebr=ka&eign=ka), say, words ending in `-ung` that are masculine.  Surprisingly it provides nothing. In Wiktionary every word is nicely indexed and free access. Hence an analogous search should be, in principle, possible.

- Does there exist a way to perform that "advanced search" in Wiktionary?

Comment: Könnte daran liegen, dass alle Wörter mit -ung [feminin](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/ung.html?lang=de) sind?!

Comment: @Em1 Eben habe ich die `-ung` Endung gewählt, um keine lange Liste zu kriegen. Etwa "Ursprung, Sprung (+abgeleitete Nomen)" und ein paar mehr.

Comment: Ach, *Sprung* und *Schwung* sind Ausnahmen... Damn it, warum findet er die nicht?

Comment: @Em1 Genau. Die Frage lautet dann auch "Wie findet man statistisch Ausnahmen?"

Comment: Das ist denk ich ein Bug. Du findest Sprung, wenn du allgemein suchst. Wahrscheinlich fehlt da einfach in der Datenbank die Information, um was für einen Worttypen es sich handelt.

Comment: @Em1 Ich glaube es hat eher zu wenige Wörter. Denn es gibt mehr als [nur 80 weibliche Nomen](http://www.owid.de/suche/elex/erweitert?pattern=p_end&wort=ung&ortho=ka&lsanz=ka&wortart=nom&gram=nom_1&wobi=ka&semk=ka&parad=ka&gebr=ka&eign=ka) mit `-ung`-Endung.

Comment: @c.p. das ist für eine Datenbankabfrage, die ja relativ simpel ist, nicht weiter von Bedeutung, wie viele Wörter es tatsächlich sind.

Answer (score 2):

In Wiktionary you can use the asterik * as a wildcard
Refer to their [help talk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help_talk%3aSearching#Wildcard_searches) page about it.

[Example](http://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3aSuche&profile=default&search=%2ainnen%20Substantiv&fulltext=Search) looking for female plural endings *-innen and Substantiv

Comment: That seem to work for  `*-innen Substantiv`. It's not actually using the powerful indexing of wiktionary, but it's ok. However, [that technique doesn't work](http://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3ASuche&profile=default&search=*ung+Substantiv+M%C3%A4nnlich&fulltext=Search) for every search, e.g. the proposed above, because you are actually using the content of the wikipedia-article, not the indices for the word.