# Is there a comprehensive searchable or online dictionary with regex support?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, dictionary

I mean something equivalent of "Merriam-Webster" in English that is available as a Windows application with *full search* compatibility or *regular expressions* !

Maybe you can offer some of them to me?

Comment: German to German? What's that? Are you looking for a dictionary which is mono- and bilingual? What do you need regular expressions for? For looking up phrases? Even then you might find all expressions with a particular word by just typing this word. Can't see what regex is good for in that case. Or did you mean to find a corpus. Furthermore, Merriam-Webster provides several dictionaries. But I don't know any M-W online dictionary which provides English-German. But what they do provide is a learner's dictionary with simplified explanations and examples. So, what's it exactly you're looking for.

Comment: German to German would be Duden. For German->English and vice versa, i use translate.google.com - if you want to see different meanings of the words, simply left-click them (especially useful when translating sentences). This is a good base, but not more - don't use sentences uncorrected..

Comment: @Em1 i don't want a bilingual ... regex is so helpful for my purpose since when i can find a phrase partially grammatically by using regex in various section(synonyms,verbal illustration,etymology ... ) of definition for words . then may i collect words correlate to each-others in some ways !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[dict.cc](http://dict.cc/) supports fuzzy search. Try *iater to search words ending on "iater" or "b??t" to search words of four letters with the first a b and the last a t (like boot/boat). Search is case-insensitive and always searches German and English.

Answer (score 3):

Being this too long to be posted as a comment, it's been converted into an answer. You might be interested in the questions and answers given here:

- [Online dictionary where I can search for second half of compound noun](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/online-dictionary-where-i-can-search-for-second-half-of-compound-noun/7340#7340)
- [How to perform an advanced search of German nouns in Wiktionary restricting both gender and ending?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9727/how-to-perform-an-advanced-search-of-german-nouns-in-wiktionary-restricting-both)
- The title of this one doesn't sound like something you look for, but the answers given there might be helpful: [Einsamkeit und Zweisamkeit](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7333/einsamkeit-und-zweisamkeit/7339#7339)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your answer: http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict .  Full regular expression support.

For example: How many words in the English language have all 5 vowels in order, exactly once?

Use this search expression:

```
^[^ -aeiou]*a[^ -aeiou]*e[^ -aeiou]*i[^ -aeiou]*o[^ -aeiou]*u[^ -aeiou]*$
```

To get 11 results (3 of them common words).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the *Langenscheidt/Collins* Großwörterbuch Englisch or the *PONS* Großwörterbuch. Probably the most comprehensive one is *Muret/Sanders* Großwörterbuch Deutsch–Englisch, now also published by Langenscheidt.