# German words with three of the same letters in a row?

Tags: spelling, curiosity

Today I stumbled upon the word *Imbissstand* and was pretty fascinated by it having three of the same letters in a row (in this case, *s*) and I was wondering if there were any other German words like that.

Comment: Welcome to the German Language StackExchange. Feel free to take the [tour] or browse around [help]. Have fun.

Comment: Theoretically you could even have four identical letters in a row, though any examples I can come up with are rather contrived -- "Wollllama" (a llama made of (or producing) wool) and "Oberlaaaal" (an eel from [Oberlaa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberlaa)).

Comment: Hawaiiinseln...

Comment: @FelixPahl: Unfortunately, in German, [Lama](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lama_(Kamel)) is spelled with only one `L`.

Comment: @FelixPahl: Or simply "Aaaal".

Comment: When I was living in Zürich I came across the word *Rollladen*.

Comment: I like "Teeei".

Comment: Sauerstoffflasche und Schwimmmeister.

Comment: I just had occasion to use such a word: "Geschirrreiniger" (dish detergent). (I stuck a sign on my container of dish detergent, writing in two lines: "Geschirr- / reiniger" :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While there are no atomic words with three identical letters in a row, this pattern can sometimes be found in compounds. Compounds (the German word is *Kompositum*) are a combination of two or more words. One way to form them is by prepending a descriptive word in front of the main word (there are *many* other ways, they are all described [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)#Kompositionstypen)). Now, if such a compound creates a sequence of three times the same letter, the rule is to keep it that way. *Note: this has been changed 1996 with the 'Rechtschreibreform'*.

Some examples (from [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/zusammentreffen-von-drei-gleichen-buchstaben)):

- Brennnessel
- Schifffahrt
- grifffest
- schnelllebig

There are, however, some exceptions (these are not considered compounds):

- dennoch
- Drittel
- Mittag

Comment: Since you mention the 1996 spelling reform: Note that even before, three identical letters in a row were possible, as only triple consonants between vowels were reduced to two, leaving words such as _Seeelefant_ and _Sauerstoffflasche_ untouched.

Comment: Note that you are allowed to drop one if the three letters so "Schiffahrt" is considered correct as well.

Comment: @AlexR This is not true anymore. The Duden link in the answer above states that you may add a hyphen for readability ("Schiff-Fahrt"), but you must not drop any of the three letters even without the hyphen.

Answer (score 48):

Take an open source dictionary or a closed one, if you have access and it is in textform and a scripting language of your choice, like bash, and search yourself:

```
for c in {a..z}; do grep $c$c$c ~/lib/dicts/utf-german ; done
```

This leads to a lot of examples, starting with *Arm**eee**inheit* and ending in *We**ttt**urnen* for my dictionary.

de_de.dict, however, gives *Kl**eee**rnte* and *Skele**ttt**eil*.

Comment: +1 for the extra work

Comment: What extra work? Some regular expression engines even support back-references as in `(.)\1\1` or `(.)$1$1`, so avoiding the external `for` loop.

Comment: Where might I get such a text file?

Comment: @lejonet: Hier: http://www.heise.de/download/office/sprache/elektronische- woerterbuecher-50000505028/ oder von deutschen Linuxinstallationen. de_DE.dic  wäre ein weiterer Dateiname um danach Ausschau zu halten. OpenOffice (LibreOffice) sollte auch eine dt. Rechtschreibprüfung haben, evtl. auch mit leicht lesbarem Wörterbuch.

Comment: @lejonet [This answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/493/12485) provides a better searchable version.

Comment: Freunde der imperialistischen Gänsefüßchen informieren sich bitte hier: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php

Comment: With GNU grep on a Linux distribution this works (tested with version 2.23 on Ubuntu 16.04): `egrep --color=auto '(.)\1\1' /usr/share/dict/*`

Answer (score 16):

## Rules

If I didn’t miss something, the [official regulations](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) specify triple letters only implicitly, because they contain no rule for collapsing them into two, except for the three “exceptions” *Drittel, Mittag, dennoch* in § 4 (8). Three equal letters are mentioned as a reason to use a hyphen in § 45:

> **§ 45** Man kann einen Bindestrich setzen zur Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile, zur Gliederung unübersichtlicher Zusammensetzungen, zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen oder **beim Zusammentreffen von drei gleichen Buchstaben**.
>   Dies betrifft (…)
>   **(4)** Zusammentreffen von drei gleichen Buchstaben in Zusammensetzungen (…)

Duden is more explicit in [Regel 169](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/zusammentreffen-von-drei-gleichen-buchstaben).

As has been mentioned, this has also been possible in most classic orthographies of German in certain cases. The usual restriction was that a consonant (but not *h*) immediately followed the sequence, which would basically be limited to *r* or *l* after *f, p* or *t*. 
This old rule had been understood worse than the new one, but the reform has been met with some criticism, too: mostly for aesthetic reasons, some people would rather have all such instances of three letters replaced by just two. This would rarely yield ambiguity as in *Bettuch = [ bet(en) | Bett ] + Tuch*.

## Frequency

Still, the phenomenon is not encountered all that often, because for it to happen, a letter needs to appear twice at the end of the first part of the compound and once at the start of the second part, e.g. *Geschirr + Reiniger = Geschirrreiniger*. 
Since a final schwa *e* may disappear from a noun and any suffix from a verb stem, the left-hand base word does not need to end in a double letter, e.g. *Pappe + Plakat = Pappplakat* and *dämmen + Material = Dämmmaterial*.

### Possible sequences

Anyhow, the only triple letters possible in German (without place names and foreign spellings) are ***fff, lll, mmm, nnn, ppp, rrr, sss, ttt* and *aaa, eee***. One could also contrive examples for *ooo* or *ooö*, e.g. *Zoo + Ordnung = Zooordnung*, and for the “soft” letters *bbb, ddd, ggg*, e.g. *Ebbe + Brandung = Ebbbrandung, Kladde + Deckel = Kladddeckel, Egge/eggen + Gerät = Egggerät*, but *ddd* in particular feels unnatural. 
There would also be lots of instances of *ckk, tzz, chh* (standing in for **kkk, *zzz, *hhh*), but few people seem interested in those, although maybe it’s one reason why we don’t have *kk, zz, hh* in regular German graphotactics.

The most common sequence, by far, is *sss*. It didn’t occur at all with the older orthography, because the first two letters would always have been written as eszett *ß* (and are still in *Litfaßsäule*). It’s somewhat frequent in street signs, e.g. *Schlossstraße*. Common left-hand components include *Schuss, Schluss, Fluss, Guss, Pass, Genuss, Nuss, Prozess; messen, essen; nass*.

All cases of *lll* are also new, because there couldn’t be a consonant following. Most compounds are ones with *still, schnell, hell, voll; fallen, rollen; Kontrolle, Müll, Ball* with derivates of *stilllegen* making the majority.

Most cases of *fff*, which is about as common as *lll*, are compounds of *Schifffahrt* or *Stoff*, especially in (applied) chemistry (*Sauerstoff, Kohlenstoff, Stickstoff, Kunststoff, Schadstoff, Baustoff, Werkstoff*) and fashion. Some of them existed before, especially with *frei* or *Flasche* as second part.

Both *mmm* and *ttt* account for a relevant number of further cases.
The other possibilities, *nnn, ppp, rrr* and *eee*, are rare, although found in some “common” words like *Brennnessel* and *Schneeeule*.

The only letter that may appear doubled at the start of a native German word is *a*, e.g. in *Aal* and *Aas*, but it doesn’t occur doubled at the end of native words, so any four-letter repetition would be an artificial construed example, e.g. **Sanaaaal* ‘eel from the capital of Yemen’. 
That’s also why *aaä* impossible, while *äaa* might be construed, e.g. **Säaas*. 
I suggest to make use of the optional hyphen in the rare case of *aaa*, others recommend it for all cases of triple vowels, or at least in nouns.

### Top Ten

The [Derewo 320000 corpus](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html) includes 457 examples (0.14% or less than 1 in 700 words), by the way. The 10 most frequent ones are:

1. *Missstand* #7398
2. *Schifffahrt* #8858
3. *stilllegen #10506, Stilllegung* #10819
4. *Anschlussstelle* #11050
5. *Schlussstrich* #12644
6. *Stillleben* #14243
7. *Eisschnelllauf* #19875
8. *Fitnessstudio* #20613
9. *Essstörung* #23298
10. *Schlussspurt* #23406

## Style

In handwriting, many people will intuitively form ligatures for the first two letters. 
In digital fonts, designers should use the technology available to them to select distinct glyphs at the compound inner boundary.

For *ttt* and *fff* it’s common, for instance, to have the horizontal line cross the first two letters without interruption or to make it only appear on the right-hand side of the stem in the final letter, e.g. ⟨ﬀf⟩ or ⟨ffﬂ⟩. 
In *aaa*, one could mix open and closed variants, i.e. ⟨ɑaa⟩ or ⟨aɑɑ⟩.

Since *ß* is now treated like a letter and not a ligature, it’s more difficult to suggest something for *sss*. If the long style was still in use, it could simply be ⟨ssſ⟩. If nothing else, the inter-character kerning should be adjusted.

Comment: @MarchHo Der findet sich neben _Nausikaaaaaalsuppe, Raaaar, Unfalllloyd, Zoooologe_ auch in der [FAQ zur Usenetgruppe de.etc.sprache.deutsch](http://faql.de/rechtschreibung.html#dreigleiche). Vielleicht etwas korrekter wird die Stadt ⟨Sanaʼa⟩ transliteriert, aber es schreibt ja auch niemand ⟨Hawaiʻi⟩.

Comment: ⟨ssſ⟩ müsste ⟨sſs⟩ sein, oder? Kein wort kann mit dem langen S anfangen, glaubte ich.

Comment: Important that you mentioned the ß -> ss change which creates many new "sss" compunds.

Comment: @Max: Ganz im Gegenteil, am Anfang von Wörtern wurde ausschließlich das lange s genutzt (sofern sie kleingeschrieben wurden). Selbst innerhalb von Morphemen war das runde s ziemlich selten.

Comment: Was @Wrzlprmft sagt. Klassisch wäre ⟨ſsſ⟩ geschrieben worden bzw. mit Ligatur halt ⟨ßſ⟩, weil das lange Es der Normalfall war. Meine – für die Masse unbrauchbare – Idee war, das Prinzip umzukehren: statt des runden Es als spezielle Form am Ende würde das lange Es als spezielle Form am Anfang stehen. Handschriftlich sieht mein End-Es übrigens ein bisschen aus wie ⟨ɔ⟩, d.h. der untere, links offene Bogen macht fast den ganzen Buchstabenkörper aus.

Comment: @Crissov wie kommt man denn bei Nausikaa + Aalsuppe auf 6 a ?

Comment: @haheute Die Quelle ist doch angegeben und verlinkt.

Comment: Litfaßsäule bedarf auch keiner Rechtschreibreform, weil sie nach Herrn Litfaß benannt ist.

Answer (score 11):

The German dictionary linked to by [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/493/12485) can be searched with a simple regex (for example using Notepad++).

The dictionary file returned 3637 hits for the regex search `(.)\1{2,}`. Unfortunately, there were no hits in the dictionary for 4 or more repeats.

An interesting hit that hasn't been mentioned is **Flussschifffahrt** (double triplets in a single word), which was found with the regex `(\D)\1{2,}.*(\D)\2{2,}`

The full list is linked to on [this pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/3381674). It is excerpted below:

```
Line 2: AAA
Line 4460: Abfalllager
Line 4461: Abfalllagern
Line 4462: Abfalllagers
Line 4463: Abfallloch
Line 4464: Abfalllöcher
Line 4465: Abfalllöchern
Line 4466: Abfallloches
Line 1736925: Zugschlussstellen
Line 1739001: Zündanlassschalter
Line 1739002: Zündanlassschaltern
Line 1739003: Zündanlassschalters
Line 1752302: Zwangsstilllegung
Line 1752303: Zwangsstilllegungen
Line 1756893: Zwerchfelllücke
```

Comment: Interesting that there doesn't seem to be the simple "Stilllegung" or "Anlassschalter". The longer I look at such words the more I favour dividing them with a hyphen. They are an imposition (if I may trust my dictionary).

Answer (score 8):

**Geschirrreiniger** (crockery cleaner)
and **Nussschokolade** (nut chocolate)

Comment: These are just two random examples. We’re looking for more elaborate answers here.

Comment: @Crissov Na und? Die Frage ist auch nur ein Zweizeiler, ob's da noch mehr Worte gibt.

Comment: Soll er etwa eine andere Antwort kopieren und seine zwei Beispiele hinzufügen? Und +1 weil ich Nussschokolade mag.

Comment: Totally fair, productive answer.

Answer (score 4):

Schrubbbürste… Some English-German online dictionaries have wildcard search options that you can use to find compound words with letter triplets. On [dict.cc](http://dict.cc) and [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org), type in, e.g., `*eee*`, `*fff*`, `*sss*`, `*ttt*`, or `*lll*`

Answer (score 0):

*Hawaiiinseln*; 3 of the same letters is common but 3 i's?

Answer (score 0):

**Es geht auch mit 4 gleichen Buchstaben hintereinander.**

Eine [Oothek](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oothek) ist ein Ort, an dem Eier aufbewahrt werden. In der Zoologie werden damit die Ei-Pakete von bestimmten Insektenarten bezeichnet.

Aber dieses Wort eignet sich auch hervorragend als Bezeichnung für einen Ort, an dem Eier gesammelt und aufbewahrt werden, vergleichbar mit einer Bibliothek für Bücher, Ludothek für Spiele oder Videothek für Videos.

Prädestiniert für das Führen einer Oothek ist natürlich ein Zoo, denn dort leben viele verschiedene Tierarten, und darunter sind viele, die Eier legen. So ein Zoo könnte seine Eiersammlung dann in einer Oothek den Besuchern präsentieren. Um dabei herauszustreichen, dass diese Oothek keine gewöhnliche Oothek, sondern die eines Zoos ist, könnte man sie wie folgt nennen:

## Zoooothek

Und schon hat man ein schönes Wort, das man in einem deutschen Satz verwenden kann, in dem 4 gleiche Buchstaben aufeinander folgen.