# »ck«, »tz« ,»vv« und »ww« als Sonderfälle von Doppelkonsonanten

Tags: spelling

Alle Konsonanten können im Deutschen doppelt vorkommen, um die kurze Dauer des vorangehenden Vokals zu signalisieren.

> bb, dd, ff, tt *etc.*

Manche davon verhalten sich anders, als die anderen.

Warum (aus historischen oder praktischen Gründen) existieren nicht die Verbindungen **kk** und **zz**, sondern werden durch **ck** bzw. **tz** ersetzt?

Aus welchem Grund kommt im Deutschen das **vv** und das **ww** so gut wie gar nicht vor? (Außer vielleicht *Struwwelpeter*)? Gibt es eine Erklärung dafür, wieso vor einem *v* und einem *w* keine kurzen Vokale auftreten?

In der Frage lasse ich bewusst *jj*, *hh*, *qq* und *xx* als nichtrelevante Konsonantenkombination außen vor.

Comment: Das scheinen mir zwei völlig verschiedene Fragen zu sein. Würdest du den Beitrag bitte auf eine reduzieren und die andere separat stellen?

Comment: Die Frage ist: wieso gibt es Abweichungen für k, z, v und w? Ich fasse das als eine (breit gefächerte) Frage auf...

Comment: *Akkumulator*? *Pizza*?

Comment: Fragst du oder antwortest du? Es sind Lehnwörter, sie werden hier nicht betrachtet (Mokka, Mekka, Razzia genauso wenig).

Comment: @BarthZalewski Was bedeutet deiner Meinung nach ein "?" - eine Frage oder eine Antwort? Ich frage, ausformuliert, wie Du die genannten Wörter betrachtest, insbesondere, da Deine Frage Lehnwörter nicht ausschließt.

Comment: Dann muß ich dafür stimmen, die Frage als „zu weit“ zu schließen. Bei _ck_ und _tz_ geht es um rein orthographische Konventionen; bei _vv_ und _ww_ dagegen ist der springende Punkt (wie du selbst schon in der Frage anreißt), warum es normalerweise kein [v] nach kurzem Vokal im Wortinneren gibt. – Die bisher einzige Antwort zeigt das Problem deutlich, guidot hat sich nur kleine Teilaspekte herausgepickt, statt die gesamte Frage anzugehen.

Comment: ... weswegen die Antwort von guidot unvollständig ist und somit auch nicht das +1 verdient hat. Ich sehe keinen Grund, nur weil für bestimmte Buchstaben unterschiedliche Gründe vorliegen mögen, jeden Buchstaben in einer eigenen Frage zu diskutieren. Diese Frage ist — so wie sie da steht — absolut OK. Es sollte einzig noch angeführt werden, ob nur germanische Wörter oder auch alles was wir importiert haben eingeschlossen werden. (Auch wenn das implizit klar ist, weil sonst die Frage nichtig deklariert wäre.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diese verwandten Phänomene lassen sich auf verschiedene Art beschreiben und erklären. Am üblichsten ist wohl ein phonotaktischer Ansatz, der mit historischen Entwicklungen und Zufällen der Graphematik in Verbindung gebracht wird, im Ergebnis also eine diachrone phonographische Theorie. Ich werde im Folgenden versuchen, die Orthographie rein aus der Schrift heraus zu erklären, was deutlich weniger verbreitet ist, aber m.W. gibt es bisher kein insgesamt befriedigendes Modell.

> **Die folgende Antwort ist noch nicht fertig und wird in den nächsten Tagen ergänzt und überarbeitet.**

## [Graphotaktik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphotaktik)

Verdoppelte Konsonantbuchstaben inkl. *ck* und *tz* (sowie *qu* und *ng/nk*) können im modernen deutschen Schriftsystem nur 1) am Ende eines Morphems/Wortes nach einem Vokalbuchstaben oder 2) zwischen zwei Kerngraphemen (Vokalbuchstaben: *a, e, i, o, u, [y], ä, ö, ü, [é]*) stehen. Das heißt, ein Randgraphem (Konsonant) kann nie vorausgehen und nur folgen, wenn er einem anderen Morphem angehört, insbesondere Flexionssuffixe wie in *rann+te*, *sing+st* oder *setz+t*. Bis weit ins 19. Jahrhundert gab es auch Schreibungen wie **Ammt* (und **Ambt*) oder **unnd*.

Außerdem müssen die Vokalbuchstaben auf beiden Seiten innerhalb eines Morphems einfach sein, d.h. Digraphen für Diphthonge (*ai, au, ei, eu, äu …*), Verdoppelungen (*aa, ee, oo* vor *r, l, t, (s, f)* und *ie* zusätzlich vor *b, d, g, ß*) und *h*-Schreibungen (*ah, eh, oh, uh, äh, öh, üh* vor *l, m, n, r, (t)*, ∅) sind dort ausgeschlossen, aber bspw. *offizi+ell* und *re+ell* erlaubt. In manchen Lehnwörtern, scheinbar v.a. aus dem Französischen, sind allerdings bestimmte Doppelvokalbuchstaben als „einfach“, bspw. in *Chauffeur* (→ *Schofför*) oder *Sierra*, oder die Doppelkonsonantbuchstaben als speziell anzusehen, bspw. in *Medaille*. Ansonsten findet sich immer eine Morphemgrenze innerhalb des scheinbaren Doppelbuchstaben, bspw. *viel+leicht* oder *aus+sehen*. Ist diese nicht (mehr) offensichtlich, kommt es vermehrt zu Fehlschreibungen wie **vieleicht*.

Nur dort, wo *ß* in der Rechtschreibung des 20. Jahrhunderts oder *ch* die o.g. Restriktionen erfüllen, können sie ggf. als Ersatzschreibungen für *ss* bzw. *hh* angesehen werden (vgl. *sehen ↔  Sicht, Vieh ↔ Viecher*). Die Schweizer Praxis, alle *ß* durch *ss* zu ersetzen, verstößt daher gegen die gewachsene Graphotaktik des Deutschen!
Zwar ähnlich aber doch entscheidend anders verhält es sich übrigens mit *pf*, denn erstens kommen *pp* und *ff* ebenfalls vor und zweitens kann es auch am Morphemanfang (*Pferd*) sowie nach *m* und selten *r* stehen (*Kampfkarpfen*).

Die „langen“ Konsonantbuchstaben (nach [Primus] bzw. [Fuhrhop/Buchmann]) kommen jeweils in einer „weichen“ und einer „harten“ Variante vor (*b, d, g, v/w* vs. *p, t, k, f*), wobei erstere verdoppelt nicht am Wortende stehen kann, weswegen die entsprechenden [Dreifachbuchstaben praktisch nicht vorkommen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28375/german-words-with-three-of-the-same-letters-in-a-row/28380#28380). Sie kommen stattdessen häufig vor End-*e* vor. Phonologisch würde dies mit der Auslautverhärtung erklärt werden. 
Die Gruppe *s, ß, z* verhält sich (mitsamt *sch* und *x* sowie *c*) besonders.

Was ist nun also an *gg/kk/ck*, *ss/zz/tz*, *ff/pf/vv/ww* so besonders?

### w / f (v)

Der Buchstabe *w* ist zwar historisch aus doppeltem *v* bzw. *u* entstanden, aber in der deutschen Orthographie wird er definitiv nicht wie ein Doppelbuchstabe behandelt! Wäre es anders, müssten wir bspw.  **veiß*, **schvarz*, **zvei* und **etva* schreiben, da an den entsprechenden Stellen kein *vv* (und auch kein *uu*) vorkommen kann. Als Konsequenz aus dieser *v*-Verwendung müsste es dann auch **for* (wie *für*) heißen.

Stattdessen ist *w* der reguläre „weiche“ Gegenpart zum „harten“ *f*, während *v* unter bestimmten Umständen ein Allograph für beide ist und zwar initial für *f* (*vier, Vater*, Vokalbuchstabe muss direkt folgen) und final für *w* (*brav, naiv*, außerdem wäre eigentlich **dov* zu erwarten; Vokalbuchstabe muss direkt vorausgehen, daher nicht **fünv, *elv, *zwölv*). 
In Fremdwörtern kann *v* auch an anderen Stellen vorkommen.

Statt *kw* steht innerhalb eines Morphems stets *qu* (und nur initial oder medial ohne angrenzende Konsonantbuchstaben), wobei das *q* ausschließlich so vorkommt.

### s / ß (z, x)

Man könnte phonographisch argumentieren, dass *tz* logisch sei, weil *z* allein schon /ts/ ausgesprochen wird, also nur der erste Teilkonsonant verdoppelt wird, aber erstens kann *z* allein gar nicht an denselben Stellen vorkommen und zweitens sollte das dann auch für *x* /ks/ gelten, aber dessen theoretische Verdoppelung *kx* oder *cx* existiert genauso wenig wie *xx* (während *zz* immerhin in Fremwörtern vorkommt), stattdessen gibt es regulär *chs* (und manchmal *cks*) zwischen Vokalen (*wachsen, wechseln, drechseln*, *Ochse, Buchse, Büchse*, aber *Hexe* und *Nixe*) sowie am Wortende (*Fuchs, Luchs, Flachs, Dachs, Wachs* vs. *Klecks*) neben dem seltenen einfachen *x* (*Axt*) und End-*ks* in Lehnwörtern mit Pluralwurzel (*Koks, Keks*).

Eisenberg führt das Vorhandensein von Doppelkonsonantbuchstaben übrigens, obwohl er klassisch phonographisch argumentiert, nicht auf Vokalkürze bzw. -gespanntheit zurück, sondern auf das Vorhandensein eines „Silbengelenks“ zumindest in manchen Wortformen des Flexionsparadigmas.

Wie üblich dürfen Schreibungen für Wörter aus geschlossenen Klassen abweichen, aber mir fällt kein Beispiel ein.

[Fuhrhop/Buchmann]: 

  [Neef]:

Comment: Auch wenn diese Antwort noch nicht fertig sei, bietet sie unglaublich viel Lesenswertes zum Thema und bestätigt mich darin, dass die Frage richtig (und nicht zu breit) gestellt wurde. Allein schon für die Mühe akzeptiere ich diese Antwort und warte gespannt auf weitere Teile.

Comment: In Bayern kommt Doppel-g am Morphemende recht häufig in Ortsnamen vor, z.B. *Planegg, Eggmühl*. Wie lässt sich dieses Auftreten erklären?

Answer (score 0):

Ein Aspekt:

Zitiert nach [Brockhaus (1894-96)](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=136247&textview=true)

> W, der 23. Buchstabe, im Deutschen und Englischen durch Doppelsetzung des *v* (u) entstanden [...]

Damit ist ein doppeltes v ein w und ein doppeltes w wäre ein vierfaches v...

Ein anderer:

Es ist sicher statthaft, ein abstraktes Prinzip zu verallgemeinern, nachdem das aber nicht den - bei sprachlichen Themen häufig willkürlichen - Enstehungsprozess widerspiegelt, sind Diskrepanzen nicht wirklich verwunderlich.